# SELECT max(Date) rows BEFORE running WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have this query that echoes all rows prior a particular date.

```
  SELECT MAX(h.date), h.url
    FROM HISTORY h
   WHERE h.uid = '19'
     AND h.date < (SELECT MAX(t.date) 
                     FROM History t
                    WHERE t.url = 'canabalt.com' 
                      AND t.uid = '19')
GROUP BY h.url
ORDER BY MAX(h.date) DESC
```

My problem is that I must only select rows that have max(Date).

But the where clause eliminates a number of rows that may have the max(Date) row and then looks for max(Date) in the remaining fields.

How can I first SELECT max(Date) and only afterwards run the WHERE clauses.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by `must only select rows that have max(Date)` and `looks for max(Date) in the remaining fields`.  Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try placing your criteria in the Having clause which is processed after the Group By clause.

```
Select Url, Max(Date) As MaxDate
From History
Where UID = '19'
Group By Url
Having  Max( Date ) <   (
                        Select Max( H1.Date )
                        From History As H1
                        Where H1.URL = 'canabalt.com' 
                            And H1.UID = '19'
                        )
Order By Max( Date ) Desc
```